# How can i embedd a java applet in blogger

Tags: java, applet, blogger

How can i embed a java applet in blogger. I am writing a blog on blog spot.com and I want to attach a java applet in that. Is it possible to do so? if yes, then how?

I tried to write this code in blog's html tab

```
<applet code="calculator.class" height="500" width="500"></applet>
```

but it doesn't work...

Comment: However, as @GhostCat says, using applets isn't the best thing to do and maybe won't be supported by your browser at all.

Comment: @Raj java 9 will deprecate the support for applets. Also applets are not already supported on Edge and Chrome so could be better to find an alternative for achieve your goal.

Answer (score 2):

You don't.

Probably nobody told you so far, but applets are "dead technology". The only reason to do anything with Applets in 2016 is because you are working in some company that still uses them for some of their internal stuff. Then, and only then you should be spending your time on learning/programming applets. But in any other case, you would be wasting your time.

You see, browser like chrome have stopped supporting Java/applets quite some months ago.

Nobody does reasonable front work using applets any more. In other words: look into JavaScript or any of the huge frameworks around that. And figure how to use something like that instead of applets.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @Gjhuizing Some problem cant be solved. They should be **avoided**. I didnt bother to look up even for documentation how to do that; because said: there is **absolutely no** point in using applet for some "open in the world" service like blogger.

Comment: As applets can be embed in html file which are supported by mozilla firefox..and blog also uses the html. So there must be an option to attach an applet in the blog....

Comment: Not sure what else to tell you. Even when it is still technically possible to use applets... That will not help you attracting audience. To the contrary! When confronted with applets the vast majority of people will **leave** your site! But if you really want to go there... You already got a link with the things that you need to know about.p

Comment: @GhostCat - that link is embedding the applet in browser..I hava already embed my applet in html page and it is working in Mozilla..but using the same concept in blog...it is creating an error - 'class not found'

Comment: Dont get me wrong, but I have the feeling that you have *no* idea what you are doing. The DUP question starts with "I am having trouble embedding my applet into a webpage". In order to "embed" something into a blog means that you need access to the HTML source that is generated. And maybe, just mabye: the reason why you have so many difficulties is because the blogger.com folks really dont care about all about folks that wish to use applets in 2016? Finally: i am pretty sure that such a large thing as that site has some "user forums" - maybe you get some more helpful answers there.